# Can we add sentences with "von" and "bis" to specify a period of time

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

I know how we can use "von" and "bis" to specify a period of time with numbers only like this example:

"Er hat von 1980 bis 1985 bei uns als Arzt angefangen zu arbeiten."

So can we add sentences with "von" and "bis" to specify a period of time including numbers and using commas? Like this example:

"Er hat von 1980, nach Abschluss seines Bachelorstudiums, bis 1985, zur Zeit des Kriegsausbruchs, bei uns als Arzt angefangen zu arbeiten."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence doesnt make sense. You can't start ("anfangen") five year long as a doctor.

You may say

> Er hat von 1980 bis 1985 bei uns als Arzt gearbeitet.

or

> Er hat 1980 bei uns als Arzt angefangen und arbeitete bis 1985.

With details you may say

> Er hat von 1980, nach Abschluss seines Bachelorstudiums, bis 1985, der Zeit des Kriegsausbruchs, bei uns als Arzt gearbeitet.

But I would prefer

> Er hat nach dem Abschluss seines Bachelorstudiums 1980 bis zum Kriegsausbruch 1985 bei uns als Arzt gearbeitet."

An additional remark: You write once 'ihres Bachelorstudiums'. *Ihres* is female. You wrote more often "Er" (not "Sie") and "Arzt" (not "Ärztin"), so I guess you want to express a male (or [neutral](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum)) version.

Comment: Ich bin da nicht so sicher. Für einen Zeitraum, der so weit zurückliegt, können auch 5 Jahre eine Anfangszeit sein.

Comment: @Nafmee If you want to talk about a single event which lies within a range of time you use "*zwischen*" and "*und*" instead: "*He arrived here some day between 1980 and 1983.*" would be: "*Er kam hier (irgendwann) zwischen 1980 und 1983 an.*"